# how to Create Dropdown list for next window in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

how do I create Dropdown list in the next window after clicking button in the first screen, I tried to initiate the button in the kv file just to have a button in the ModelWindow screen but the next problem is the button variable in ModelWindow class is gone. the button variable is needed for the lista method in order to activate dropdown

**Python File**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class ModelWindow(Screen):
    def window(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        label = Label(text='LABEL')
        button = Button(text='Selecione', font_size=30, size_hint_y=0.15, on_release=self.lista)
        box.add_widget(label)
        box.add_widget(button)

        self.dropdown = DropDown()  # Create the dropdown once and keep a reference to it
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(button, 'text', x))

        for index in range(10):  # create the buttons once
            btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44,
                            on_release=lambda btn: print(btn.text))  # bind every btn to a print statement
            btn.text = 'Value %d' % index
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)
        return box

    def lista(self, button):
        # dropdown = DropDown()  <---- DON'T NEED THIS
        # button.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)  <---- DON'T NEED THIS
        self.dropdown.open(button)  # you need this to open the dropdown
        # print(button.text)
  

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("proj.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

**Kv file**

```
 WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
    ModelWindow:

<ModelWindow>:
    name: "model"
 
<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            text: "Select Model"
            on_press:
                app.root.current = "model" 
                      
        Button:
            text: "Test Model"

        Button:
            text: "Create New Model"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "second" 
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

My I ask if anyone knows how to make a dropdown list in the next window? should I write it in the kv file or the python itself? Thank youu

Comment: I can't follow you, could you please be more specific ?

Comment: @ApuCoder I want to create an next window using screen manager, it has a "list" of buttons that are clickable and can give output "On_press" its more like recycleview but easier version, thats why I tried dropdown, because I really cant understand how to use recycleview with kv file

Answer (score 0):

If I get your point correctly, you want to initialize the `ModelWindow` class. In order to do that you can simply call the method `window` in `__init__` with some modifications or define everything directly in `__init__` as,

```py
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        label = Label(text='LABEL')
        ...
        # Same as in your method `window`.
            ...
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)
        self.add_widget(box)
```